# Wildcard Subdomain using Homestead/Laravel

Tags: laravel, homestead

Have my app configured as

myapp.app

I was wondering if I can get subdomains to work like

ilike.myapp.app, ihate.myapp.app...

But without having to add it to my hosts file, as the subdomain will represent the Team of the user, and for test purposes is nice to have it accepting new instances without touching the host file.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jslim.net/blog/2015/12/01/setup-wildcard-subdomain-in-laravel-homestead/

Comment: Tried this and didn't work... Will check again later. If there's no simple sollution will just stick to adding it manually! @IvankaTodorova